# Accesing Spring-Boot WebApplication running in Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

so I got a running Spring-Boot Application that is deployed into a Docker container. I mapped the port of the application to a port on my portainer which runs multiple Docker container. Everything seems fine but if i try to acces the WebApplication i get a Connection Refused Error.

---

Mapping of Docker Port to Application Port:

[image: Port Mapping]

DockerFile:

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD target/r750explorer-1.0.war app.war
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.war'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
EXPOSE 8750
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.war" ]
```

---

I can verify that the App is running inside the Docker via the Portainer logs.

Everything is build with a Jenkins running these commands:

```
sh 'docker rm -f ' + dockerInstanceName + ' && echo "container ' + dockerInstanceName + ' removed" || echo "container ' + dockerInstanceName + ' does not exist"'
echo 'Docker deploy ...'
sh 'docker build -t ' + dockerInstanceName + '/r750:"${BUILD_ID}" .'
sh 'docker run -p 49175:8750 --expose 8750 --name ' + dockerInstanceName + ' -d ' + dockerInstanceName + '/r750:"${BUILD_ID}"'
```

Edit: Docker Logs of Container:

```
: Channel 'R750Explorer:8750.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
: started _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger
: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 17 ms
: Started ServerConnector@49c386c8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:8750}
: Jetty started on port(s) 8750 (http/1.1)
: Started Application in 13.441 seconds (JVM running for 16.363)
```

Comment: Please don't post code (`Dockerfile`) and config as images, that makes them highly unreadable.

Comment: Can you post logs? using `docker logs <container_name>`

Comment: what URL are you accessing?

Comment: I'm using this URL: <server>:49175. This works fine with the other Containers that are running on the portainer. I will post the logs asap. And thanks for the Tipp with the images. Its my first post here so every help appreciated :)